# Defining Schema with graphql-tools

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am trying to define my schema for my API. I am running into an issue where each resource has many different sections. Ideally I would like to just be able to say sections is a JSON object rather than define all the different modules within the sections. Is there a way I can do this? As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a `JSON` type definition using `graphql-tools`

```
// Define your types here.
const typeDefs = `

  type Resource {
    id: ID,
      title: String!,
        slug: String!,
      path: String!,
      template: String!,
      published: String!,
      sections: Sections
    }

    type Sections {
      // ...
    }

    type Query {
      allLinks(filter: LinkFilter): [Link!]!
      findResource(filter: ResourceFilter): [Resource!]!
    }

`;
```

Comment: A JSON scalar will work here, but a word of caution is in order: you lose quite a few of the benefits of GraphQL if you start using JSON scalars. For instance, you will not get automatic type checking for that object (if you've set that up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to import a custom JSON scalar. [This module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json) is one of the more popular ones available.

Anywhere in your typeDefs, add the following line:

```
scalar JSON
```

And then inside the `resolvers` object you pass to `makeExecutableSchema`:

```
const GraphqlJSON = require('graphql-type-json')

const resolvers = {
  Query: //queries
  Mutation: //mutations
  // All your other types
  JSON: GraphqlJSON
}
```

One word of warning: anytime you use JSON as a scalar, you lose flexibility. Part of the charm of GraphQL is that it allows clients to only query the fields they need. When you use JSON, your client will only be able to either query the whole chunk of JSON, or not at all -- they won't be able to pick and choose parts of it.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for thanks. I am not too worried about loosing flexibility for the `sections` response as I will never need to pick single sections. They are always used collectively.